# Flink doesn't goes up such as Running-state on Openshift 4.4.9

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, apache-flink

I'm trying the following command to build Apache Flink seamlessly on openshift 4.4.9 google cloud. But pods makes the following mistake all the time, and Flink doesn't goes up such as Running-state.

What do you think is the problem and how can I fix it ?

Here is an example of an issue that I get;

Port:           
Host Port:      
State:          Waiting
Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State:     Terminated
Reason:       Completed

Here is the Flink DockerFile to find out the problem:

https://github.com/keremceliker/flgkrc

I need to run Flink on Centos/ImagesPod. (Just in case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue when re-produce Dockerfile code and to login registry.redhat.io. Apache Flink works well now on OpenShift by DockerImage !

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't get an error and the reason for termination is "Completed", it means that the pod does what you ask it to do. The pod would stay alive if its main process would still be running.

From your Dockerfile, the main process is `help` (defined by `CMD ["help"]`). My best guess is that this command prints a help message and exists, thus triggering the termination of the pod as well.

You should remove the CMD declaration or adjust it by passing a command that keeps a process running.